# Planning to visit my girlfriend in UK, what should I fill in the relationship status?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am planning to visit my girlfriend in UK. She left for UK in Sep 2019. I was supposed to visit her during April 2020 but due to Covid-19, could not travel. When I applied for my visa in 2020, I never used the word "girlfriend" anywhere in the application. I simply wrote "friend" throughout the visa application.

I am planning to visit her in upcoming months. While filling the form, I was asked the question - ***What is your current relationship status***.

I am in a relationship with my GF since 2018. Should I submit ***Single*** or ***Unmarried Partner*** as my response to this question.

Another related question is - should I use "*friend*" or "*girlfriend*" word throughout the visa application. Please note that when I applied for visa in 2020, I mentioned that I am planning to visit my "*friend*". I read somewhere on this site that this could cause issues later on when you are applying for dependent visa. I have also read on various forums that use of the word "girlfriend" has an apparent negative connotation. Please guide me on this.

Note -

- She is currently on a Tier-2 health&care work visa since Mar 2021 and
  I might join her as an dependent in future.
- We are both Indian citizens. I do not have any travel history to any country.

Comment: Rule no1 for visa applications is always to tell the truth. State ‘single’ for your relationship status and refer to your GF as ‘girlfriend’ in the application if she is the main reason for you wanting to visit the UK. If the visa is approved it would be wise for your GF to be at the airport to meet you, and to be prepared to get a call from a Border Officer as part of your landing interview.

Comment: @Traveller would it be an issue that in my last application I mentioned "friend" and this time I would be mentioning "girlfriend", could this change alone be a ground for refusal?

Comment: Aak, you could explain that your relationship with the lady has intensified in the mean time.

Comment: @Wileke It would be difficult to prove using Whatsapp chats and calls. I am planning to provide a history of our relationship since it started in July 2018 along with photos, proof of trips we went together until Sep 2019. Hopefully the visa officers won't notice that I used "friend" in my last application.

Comment: Do not assume the officer does not notice. Be prepared to explain that your knowledge of your feelings is clearer now, that you are now willing to claim it being a special friendship, while last time you were not as sure yet.

Comment: @Willeke in that case, there is no point in trying to show  photos, proof of trips before my previous visa application as that would be contrasting.

Comment: Here, we don't know OP's gender. Why do you need a gender specific term for your friend when visiting UK? Suppose you don't want to say boyfriend or girlfriend, what else can you put but 'friend'?

Comment: @Weather Vane I am Male. She is my girlfriend so saying a friend in the application form sounds kinda deceptive and it may cause issues at border control or in case of dependent visa in future.

Comment: Are there different levels of friend status? A special friend may cease to be that on the day that you meet up, for some reason, but a fiance or partner is rather more solid, although the same might still apply.

Comment: @Aak Is your girlfriend paying any of your trip expenses and/or will you be staying with her? Have you met in person? I think you might be over-focusing on ‘proving’ a relationship when what will possibly matter even more to UKVI will be your intention to leave at the end of the trip. Without a prior travel history you’ll need to demonstrate a compelling reason to go home

Comment: @Traveller She won't be paying for my trip. I have met her in person multiple times from July 2018 to Sep 2019 when she left for UK.She stays in a double room in a house with 3 other people. Since I would need to self-isolate for 10 days. I am fairly certain India would at-best make it to Amber list in upcoming months and travellers from Amber list can isolate with friends and family. Now I am not sure whether I am allowed to isolate in a double room with her. I am thinking of isolating 10 days in a hotel and then go to her place.

Comment: @Traveller I have a Job in India since July 2018 and earning around 900 GBP per month. I would definitely book a return ticket along with letter from employer allowing me to take a leave for 20-25 days. I hope this is enough evidence that I would leave the UK

Comment: @Aak You cannot isolate in a double room with your girlfriend. The ‘how to quarantine safely’ rules state you should stay in a well ventilated room with an outside window that can be opened, separate from other people in your home. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england

Comment: @Traveller I would need permission from her land lord in case I want to isolate in her residence. I would book a separate hotel room to avoid this. After my isolation, I am allowed to stay with her in her room? She has tenancy agreement for the room. Would I still require permission from her land lord to stay with her even after isolation?

Comment: @Aak What your GF's landlord does or does not allow will be in your GF's letting agreement.